# Return object from function to which JSON is passed

Tags: javascript, function, return

Dears,

I have a function, to which i input JSON data

```
function getTotals(users){

users = data;


allUsers = users.length;
active = 0;
women = 0;
men = 0;
lastActive = 0;

for (elm in users){
    if (users[elm].active){
        active++;

        if (users[elm].gender == "Female"){
            women++;
        } else if (users[elm].gender == "Male") {
            men++;
        } else if (users[elm].last_login){
            var lastLogin = new Date (users[elm].last_login);
            var lastMonths = lastLogin.getMonth()-6;
            var lastYears = lastLogin.getFullYear();
            //console.log(lastYears);

            if (lastMonths <6 && lastMonths > -6 && lastYears >= lastLogin.getFullYear()-1){
                lastActive++;
            }
        }

    }
}
return {allUsers : allUsers, active : active, women : women, men : men, lastActive : lastActive};}
```

but i cannot display the values, when i do following:

```
var listOfUsers = document.createElement('p');
listOfUsers.textContent = "Liczba wszystkich użytkowników: "+allUsers;
document.querySelector("#row1 > div").appendChild(listOfUsers);

var listOfActive = document.createElement('p');
listOfActive.textContent =  "Liczba aktywnych użytkowników: "+active;
document.querySelector("#row2 > div").appendChild(listOfActive);


var listOfWomen = document.createElement('p');
listOfWomen.textContent = "Liczba aktywnych kobiet: "+women;
document.querySelector("#row3 > div").appendChild(listOfWomen);

var listOfMen = document.createElement('p');
listOfMen.textContent = "Liczba aktywnych mężczyzn: "+men;
document.querySelector("#row4 > div").appendChild(listOfMen);

var listOfLastActv = document.createElement('p');
listOfLastActv.textContent = "Liczba aktywnych (ost 6 mcy): "+lastActive;
document.querySelector("#row5 > div").appendChild(listOfLastActv);
```

When i do following (found here in other questions):

```
var getTotalUsers = new getTotal();
var allUsers = getTotalUsers.allUsers;
var active = getTotalUsers.active;
var women = getTotalUsers.women;
var men = getTotalUsers.men;
var lastActive = getTotalUsers.lastActive;
```

I get undefined as a result. I do not know how to fix this issue, as in next part of js, i will need to display list of active users.

Comment: Where is `data` defined?

Comment: var data;function httpGet (url) {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function (){
     
      if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {
        if (httpReq.status == 200) {
          data = JSON.parse(httpReq.responseText);
          resolve (data);
        } else {
          reject (new Error(http.Req.statusText));
        }
      }
    };
    
    httpReq.open("GET",url,true);
    httpReq.send();
   })
}

Comment: `new Promise()` returns results asynchronously. Why do you pass `users` then redefine `users` as `data`?

Comment: could you please tell me what should i pass? or i should not redefine users as data and use only data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Promise()` returns results asynchronously. You can either chain `.then()` or use `async/await` to get expected result

```js
function httpGet() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve([{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}])
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200))
  })
}

async function getTotals() {

  const users = await httpGet();

  console.log(users);
  
}

getTotals();
```

```js
function httpGet() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve([{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}])
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200))
  })
}

function getTotals() {

  const data = httpGet();

  data.then(function(users) {
    console.log(users)
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
  
}

getTotals();
```

Comment: i do have this at the end of js file getUserData()
.then(getTotals)
.catch(manageError);  also i have commented part users = data in function, and it still works, but i am not able to return obj from function - still i get undefined

Comment: Then `users = data` is not necessary. Why do you call `new getTotal()`? What is `getTotal()`? Why do you expect to get synchronous results from an asynchronous function call?

Comment: getTotals - function in which i count and display data about users

Comment: Then there is a `getTotal` function that is different from `getTotals` function?

Comment: You are also referencing variables `allUsers` instead of the property `data.allUsers` from the object that you return

Comment: i have fixed this typing, but i get in the console: zadEE3.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at new getTotals (zadEE3.js:47)
    at zadEE3.js:76

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149933/discussion-between-guest271314-and-mapta).